# Book Introduction to Logic. Patrick Suppes-Section 2.1-Excercise 4

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic

Anybody can help me with the solution of this exercise?

4. Construct a (non valid) rule of inference which by itself will satisfy Criterion II but violates Criterion I?

[image]

Thank you in advance.
Diego.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick Suppes provides an example of an inference rule in section 2.1 that satisfies the soundness Criterion I but does not satisfy the completeness Criterion II:

> From any sentence *P* we may infer *P*.

If the antecedent of the conditional, *P*, is true, then the consequent, *P*, is also true and so the rule is sound. However, it does not allow us *by itself* to derive every valid conclusion. For example, it does not allow us to derive *P v Q*. We would also need another rule for disjunction introduction.

The exercise asks us to do the something similar:

> Construct a (non valid) rule of inference which by itself will satisfy Criterion II but violates Criterion I?

We might try this:

> From any sentence *P* we may infer *Q*.

This would derive all conclusions which logically follow, but it would also derive those which do not logically follow based on a truth table. So this rule would be complete but not sound.

---

Patrick Suppes. Introduction to Logic. (1957) Van Nostrand Rheinhold.